# Running make on a makefile doesn't quite work

Tags: terminal, bash, shell

I have this makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
COMPILER=g++ -g
COMPILERSO=g++ -a +a1 -b
LIBDIR=/Users/romeovs/Desktop/rootex
CFLAGS=$(root-config --cflags)
LIBS=$(root-config --libs) -lPhysics -lThread -lMinuit -lHtml -lVMC -lEG -lGeom
ROOT=/usr/local/bin/root -b -q

.SUFFIXES=.C .o

WriteTree : WriteTree.C Event.o Event_C.so Event.h
    ${COMPILER} WriteTree.C -o  $@ Event.o Event_C.so ${CFLAGS} ${LIBS}
Event_C.so : BuildLibDico.C
     ${ROOT} BuildLibDico.C
Event.o : Event.C Event.h
    ${COMPILER} -c ${CFLAGS} Event.C
```

When I run in `make Event.o` int the command line, one would expect `make` would run:

```
${COMPILER} -c ${CFLAGS} -o Event.o Event.C
```

which should expand to

```
g++ -g -c $(root-config --cflags) -o Event.o Event.C
```

which in turn should have `$(root-config --cflags)` expanded.

Yet when I do this `make` hails:

```
g++     -c -o Event.o Event.C
```

(note the extra space between `g++` and `-c`). This in turn causes compilation errors of course.

It seems as if the expansion doesn't work properly. Running:

```
g++ -c $(root-config --cflags) -o Event.o Event.C
```

does work though.

What can I do to fix this?

---

**EDIT**

One part of the problem is fixed by Gilles answer.

Another part of the problem was that `make` didn't actually look food a makefile in the directory (it's called `WriteTree.make`), and was running the basic `g++` command.

This can be fixed by using `make -f WriteTree.make Event.o`, yet I don't know if it's good `make` behavior (I would really like it to look for itself for makefiles, not only `makefile` but every `*.make`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CFLAGS=$(root-config --cflags)` sets `CFLAGS` to the value of the make variable with the bizarre name `root-config --cflags`. Since you have no such variable, the expansion is empty. Note that make accepts either `${variable_name}` or `$(variable_name)`, and if the character following the `$` isn't an opening parenthesis or brace then it's used as a variable name (even e.g. `$foo` expands to the value of the variable named `f` followed by the two characters `oo`).

You need to double the dollar sign: `$$` expands to a single `$`, and then you'll have a shell snippet.

```
CFLAGS = $$(root-config --cflags)
LIBS = $$(root-config --libs) -lPhysics -lThread -lMinuit -lHtml -lVMC -lEG -lGeom
```

Another error is that `.SUFFIXES = .C .o` should have a colon instead of the equal sign: `.SUFFIXES: .C .o`. This doesn't matter here since you have no implicit rule.

Finally, make looks for `Makefile` (or `makefile` with some implementations; GNU make first tries `GNUmakefile`). Make only reads a single makefile in any case (not counting files reached through `include` directives). If you want to use a different makefile, you need to specify it explicitly on the command line, with the `-f` option. If you want to split your rules into several makesfiles, write a master makefile that includes them all; note that the makefiles will share a single namespace for targets and variables. In GNU make, you can include all files matched by a wildcard pattern:

```
include $(wildcard *.make)
```

Note that the file names are relative to the current directory that you invoked `make` from. If you want to look for files in the same directory as the makefile, you need to indicate it explicitly:

```
include $(wildcard $(dirname $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))/*.make)
```

Comment: Ok check my update. It explains the last paragraph of your answer.

Comment: @romeovs If you want to split your definitions and rules into several files, you still need to write a master makefile, or pass the name of a single makefile with `-f`.